# How to view the executed SQL in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure

In SequelPro there is a nice feature that will give a log of any statements that the application runs (same with Navicat I believe). For example:

[image]

Is there anything similar in SSMS where it can show the queries that the application produces behind the scenes, for example, if I do a "rename table" that it would log something like `ALTER TABLE table...` ?

Comment: I deleted my answer re SSMS 'SQL Server profiler' as it doesn't work in Azure - but maybe try the `SQL Server Profiler extension` for Azure Data Studio? I don't know if it works (and it is 'preview' still so not stable): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-profiler-extension?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @seanb fantastic -- that's really great. Not as integrated as the answer you first provided by really great for seeing visibility. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Apparently SQL Server Profiler is also deprecated - it means I need to learn the next step. Someone may have a better answer than the above given it's been 'preview' for 2 years now. One thing I found was the 'XEvent Profiler' on SSMS (recent versions) - it is at the bottom of the panel on the left. This also shows SQL as it's being run.

Comment: Hi @samuelbrody1249, is the answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the query below, it works in Azure SQL databse:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

It can view all the executed SQL queries in SSMS. It still has some limits but it's the closest answer:

[image]